# Algorithm to compare similarity of English sentences

Tags: algorithm

I have a collection of sentences, and I need to analyse them to see how similar they are.

Are there any established algorithms to do this?

I care about:

- containing the same words (ignoring inflexions for now)
- containing the same words in a similar order

I've used Levenshtein distance and n-grams for spelling before, although I'm not entirely confident if these translate to my purposes.

Naively, "I don't care about spelling differences, typos can be treated as different words" although perhaps it would be nice to account for this.

perhaps some hybrid of splitting the sentence at spaces and one of the above (or other) algorithms would be a starting point

What options are available? Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

[This paper](http://www.ischool.drexel.edu/faculty/thu/research-papers/dawak-547.pdf) compares several sentence similarity measures.  Perhaps you can use one of them as is, or modify it for your needs.

Otherwise **sentence similarity measure** is a good key term to google for.

Comment: @Andrew actually I just googled because the question raised my interest :)  I'm not familiar with the topic ... I understand that your problem may be in the technical details, which are mostly ignored in that paper (make it spelling-mistake-resitant, inflexions, etc. good that English words are barely inflected)

Answer (score 0):

To ignore inflections you should look into stemming algorithms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porter_stemmer

They reduce words to their root forms.